# PuppeteerSharp - Access a background page, that opens in a new tab, as a regular page

Tags: c#, puppeteer, reddit

I'm having issues with a program that generates reddit apps with refresh tokens from a discord command.

I've managed to get to a point, where I can generate the application, get all the relevant information, head over to https://not-an-aardvark.github.io/reddit-oauth-helper/ and from there generate the token, which opens a reddit confirmation page in a new window.

I've tried accessing it in various ways and have gone through multiple different methods, until I landed on using Target.PageAsync() to get the page.
For some reason, Puppeteer only sees the page as an iFrame and only gives this link when getting the Url property - https://www.redditmedia.com/gtm/jail?cb=8CqR7FcToPI - which doesn't lead to anywhere but seems to be related to the very first iFrame from what I've gathered in the HTML.

I've ran out of ideas on how to access the page to press quite literally one button and would appreciate any ideas or solutions on how to solve this or how to generate the refresh token without the use of an external website.

Answer (score 1):

Another two hours later and I managed to figure out a solution.

Since PuppeteerSharp was unwilling to recognize the page, I just subscribed to Browser.TargetCreated at the correct moment with a handler that, after immediately unsubscribing, will log the most recent target (in this case, a javascript calling window.open()) and take the sender as the Browser, will then try to get the pages into an array and with a bit of code to ensure that it doesn't break itself, I finally managed a solution, I feel kinda dumb after three days and 12+ hours of work.

For anyone who might run into a similar situation, here's the snippet of code that made it finally work:

```
        // Bla bla bla code to crawl or do whatever on the main page.

        // Immediately subscribe to the target created event with the event handler 
        // that will handle the background page once it has 
        // been triggered by a button, link, etc.

        browser.TargetCreated += TargetCreatedEventHandler;
    }

    static async void TargetCreatedEventHandler(object sender, TargetChangedArgs e)
    {
        // Unsubscribe from the event to 
        // make sure there are no duplicate unnecessary calls that might break the code.

        browser.TargetCreated -= TargetCreatedEventHandler;
        
        // Since I know the sender is the Browser object, 
        // I cast it it to another Browser used inside the event handler.

        Browser eventBrowser = (Browser) sender;
        
        // Get all the pages from the event browser 
        // and assume the first page is background one (for now)

        Page[] pages = await eventBrowser.PagesAsync();
        Page page = pages[0];
        int counter = 0;

        // Iterate through the pages, check if they're the page you were just on, 
        // use an int to help you keep track of of indexes. 
        // If it isn't the page you were on, assign the Page object the page 
        // with the current counter index from pages. 
        // (basically make sure it doesn't break itself with the wrong order). 
       
        foreach (var item in pages)
        {
            if (item.Url != "Main Page URL HERE")
            {
                page = pages[counter];
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        // Do whatever you need to do on your background page here   
    }
```